# Cannot return values from multiple entries in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, get

I'm trying to write a simple program to calculate density (Dens) given mass in air (A) and mass in water (B) and temperature of water (Temp).  I've made a gui with tkinter.  If I only try to get one value (ao=float(A.get())), the program works.  But when I try to add in a second value (bo), the program no longer works.  The gui no longer shows up when I run density.py.  This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        ao = float(A.get())
        #bo = float(B.get())
        #Temp1 = float(Temp.get())
        Dens.set((ao / (ao - 2)))
    except ValueError:
        pass

root = Tk()
root.title("Density Calculation")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="5 10")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

A = StringVar()
B = StringVar()
Temp = StringVar()
Dens = StringVar()

A_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=A)
A_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

B_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=B)
B_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

Temp_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=Temp)
Temp_entry.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=Dens).grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command=calculate).grid(column=3,        row=5, sticky=W)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="A").grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="B").grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="temp").grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="density is ").grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="g/cc").grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5,     pady=5)

A_entry.focus()
root.bind('<Return>', calculate)

root.mainloop()
```

When I uncomment the bo and temp1 lines in the calculate function, the program no longer puts out a gui.  I need to call those entries as part of the Dens equation.  For instance:

```
Dens.set(ao/(ao-bo))
```

How do I get the program to recognize multiple entries?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the two lines are commented out, your program works as long as the user types three properly formatted float values into the three text boxes.  (I tried it.)  The `except ValueError: pass` code in `calculate` is not a good idea.  I would either print a traceback on the console or display some kind of error message in `Dens`.  That would allow you to troubleshoot the problem and give the user some clue about what went wrong.

Comment: I guess really my question is, why does the code not work when I have the calculate function defined as:    ao = float(A.get()); bo = float(B.get()); dens.set(ao / (ao - bo))?  It doesn't even put up the gui to allow me to enter values.

Comment: That makes no sense at all, since the lines you commented out do not get executed unless <Enter> is clicked.  That can't happen unless the gui is displayed.  And the program always runs for me, whether the lines are commented out or not.  II can't see any reason why it wouldn't draw the GUI.  What happens when you try to run the program?  Do you see a traceback?  Can you put some print statements in there to see what it's doing?

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work before. I deleted the lines and then retyped them exactly the same, and now it works. Go figure.